# Java BigInteger set byte size

Tags: java, biginteger

Can I specify size for BigInteger, such that one will can get `"ffff"` for -1 two's complement, instead just `"ff"` ?

My domain logic requires such aligments.

Comment: no, you can't do that. However, you can call `BigInteger.shortValue()` to get that specific two-byte result (and `.intValue()` for a 4-byte result, etc.)

Comment: Are you confusing value and display formatting?

Comment: I am writing test, and need to check fixed size of custom data types.

Comment: BigIntegers as a whole don't have a fixed size. And I fail to see how that ("fixed size of custom data types") relates to getting `"ffff"` instead of `"ff"` for the two's complement. As others said, use `.shortValue()` for that, or simply take a look at output formatting.